# VS Code no longer showing option to view DataFrame in Data Viewer

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, visual-studio-code

I'm working with pandas in VS Code and I've been using the `View value in Data Viewer` option to look at my Data frames while debugging.

For some reason VS Code has now hidden the option for me to view my data frames and I'm not sure why or how to turn this back on again. I've tried searching for `Data Viewer` in `Preferences > Settings` but I can't find a reference to it.

For reference take a look at the image below which shows the options when I right-click a Dataframe in the debugger on the `Variables` view

[Current options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUWa2.png)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have found the answer to this. The functionality to `view Dataframe in Data Viewer` requires the  Jupyter extension to work. If you have this issue make sure you have the Jupyter extension installed

Comment: This was a saver. Thanks!